# Change ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE for WPML

Tags: plugin-wpml, warnings

I got an error:

> PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE - assumed 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <path/functions.php on line 19

So I want to change `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` to `wpml_current_language` filter. But I can't make it.

I want to change this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
        case 'AED':         
        if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ar'){        
        $currency_symbol = 'د.إ'; 
        }else{
                 $currency_symbol = 'AED'; 
            } 
        break;          
    }
    return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: Is WPML active and running then the `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` constant should already be defined - this question is probably best suited to being asked with the WPML Support team.